# Use Web Browser (Google Chrome or Firefox) to Open Web Sites from a List in File

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I have a (text) file containing a list of web site addresses. I know that I can open the file in an editor and then copy-paste the addresses to the browser address bar. That means, if I have ten addresses in that file, I will need ten copy-paste operations, which must be tedious. But is there a way to ask the browser (preferably Google Chrome or Firefox) 
to open all of them in one go in different tabs?

I am using Ubuntu, if that is related in any way to the solution you provide.

Answer (score 3):

With Firefox You can put the URLs in the command line that starts the browser:

```
firefox.exe "one.com" "two.com"
```

The quotes are necessary.  You will need of course a means of creating the start command from your text file.  A script should do that for you.

Comment: The solution is needed for Ubuntu, firefox.exe should be firefox, and the list is in a file, not command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Since the intended solution will be used Ubuntu, the solution here is for Google Chrome or Firefox under Ubuntu.

---

Open a terminal, `Ctrl-Alt-t`.
 Type `` google-chrome  `cat file-name-containing-the-URLs` ``
or `` firefox  `cat file-name-containing-the-URLs` ``. Press `Enter`

All the URLs in the above file will be opened in the browser.

---

The man pages for the above browsers show,

```
man google-chrome
```

> google-chrome [OPTION] [PATH|URL]

```
man firefox
```

> firefox [OPTIONS] [url]

So, both of the above indicate that if the URLs are provided as command line arguments, they will be launched fine.